# Switch statement in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

How to call a function and pass the parameter to switch statement in Aurelia? Here is my example:

home.html

```
<template>
<input type="text" value.bind="FruitName">
<div class="Fruit">
<a href="http://www.example.com/${TypeOfFruit(FruitName)}" target="_blank"><a>
</template>
```

home.js

```
export class Home {

  TypeOfFruit(fruits) {
    text = ""
    switch (fruits) {
      case "Banana":
        text = "Banana is good!";
        break;
      case "Orange":
        text = "I am not a fan of orange.";
        break;
      case "Apple":
        text = "How you like them apples?";
        break;
      default:
        text = "I have never heard of that fruit...";
    }
    return this.text;
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.text` should just be `text`.

Comment: and `text = ""` should be `let text = ""`

Answer (score 1):

what you need is a [value-converter](https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/value-converters/),
those are special function that can be use to transform your data using any logic you want (including your `switch`) while binding.